# Cannot connect to remote docker daemon

Tags: docker

I have a docker daemon running on machine `A` using a TCP socket:

```
sudo dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -l debug
```

If I try to interact with it from machine `A`, everything works fine, e.g.:

```
docker -H tcp://X.X.X.X:2375 info
```

But if I try to interfact from another machine `B`, I get:

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://X.X.X.X:2375. Is the docker daemon running?

In the first case (from machine `A`), I see this kind of things in the log:

```
INFO[2020-07-09T16:43:40.017694999Z] API listen on [::]:2375
DEBU[2020-07-09T16:43:43.925471288Z] Calling GET /_ping
DEBU[2020-07-09T16:43:43.926256042Z] Calling GET /v1.38/info
```

...but in the second case (from machine `B`), nothing.

When I run `tcpdump` (`sudo tcpdump -s 0 -A 'tcp dst port 2375'`) on machine `A`, I get data from machine `B`, but these never reach the docker daemon.

Any idea how to solve this? Or at least how to investigate this a bit further?

Comment: did you install ssh agent?

Comment: @TheFool Yes, ssh agent is installed on both machines.

Comment: You're aware that anyone who can reach your system over the network can basically trivially root it?  This `dockerd -H` option is insanely dangerous; I wouldn't try to debug this setup, but instead use (encrypted, authenticated) ssh to run `docker` commands on other systems when you need to.

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes I'm aware of that, but that machine is "protected" (enough for my purpose). My goal is to use this for running CI from an internal Gitlab. If I manage to have this working, I should be able to switch from local to "remote" docker by simply setting the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable, but switching to SSH + Docker would probably be much more complicated.

Comment: https://www.kevinkuszyk.com/2016/11/28/connect-your-docker-client-to-a-remote-docker-host/ this might help you\